# What happens when I purchase same non - renewable in app purchase pack again and again?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to handling inApp purchase . I have created non -renewable packs in iTunes Connect account. What happens when I purchase same pack again and again?

Comment: Do you mean consumable? Or non-renewing subscription?

Comment: There is no in-app purchase called a "pack" - There are non-consumable or consumable purchases and auto-renewing, non-renewing or free subscriptions

Comment: There are 5 types of in app purchases: Consumables, Non-Consumables, Auto-Renewable Subscriptions, Free Subscriptions, Non-Renewing Subscriptions -> https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf there is no "non renewable pack", what is that supposed to be?

Comment: non-renewing  subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

For a non-renewing subscription you are responsible for tracking the subscription end date.  If the user has an active subscription you can either prevent them from purchasing again by disabling the store functionality in your app or add an additional period onto the subscription termination date.